# Can VHD from Virtual PC 2007 be mounted under Virtual Server 2005 R2?

Tags: virtualization

I have a virtual hard disk file (VHD) created using Microsoft Virtual PC 2007.  Can this file be copied to a host running Microsoft Virtual Server 2005 R2 and be used as the basis for creating a new virtual machine?  Essentially, are the VHD file formats between the two products compatible, or do I need to create a new VHD from scratch?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

The VHD standard is common between Virtual PC, Virtual Server 2005, Hyper-V and even the bootload in Windows 7/2008 R2.

You will have to upgrade the VMAdditions/Integration Components (well you do if you move from Virtual Server 2005 to Hyper-V) to pickup the latest drivers, HAL, heartbeat services. In my experience it is easier to remove the VMAdditions prior to moving it to the new virtulaisation platform.

Good luck..

Comment: Thanks.  I had thought that to be the case, but I wanted a 2nd opinion.